# how do I get the value and text of a select field?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value and text of the selection field to come out like this but as text.

```
'1' => 'Alabama'
'2' => 'Alaska'
'3' => 'American Samoa'
..etc
```

But the results I am getting doesn’t look right, here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3UfRq/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#state").each(function() {
   $("p#out").text("'" + $(this).val() + "' => '" + $(this).text() + "'<br/>");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="state">
  <option value="1">Alabama</option>
  <option value="2">Alaska</option>
  ...
  <option value="65">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Output:

> '43' => 'AlabamaAlaskaAmerican SamoaArizonaArkansas...Wyoming'

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `"#state option"` matches only one element, so `each` calls your function only once, and `this` inside this function is the `<select>`. But you should iterate through `<option>`s. So your code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#state option").each(function() {
     $("p#out").append("'" + $(this).val() + "' => '" + $(this).text() + "'<br/>");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YNGdN/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$("#state")
```

With

```
$("#state option")
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#state option").each(function() {
   $("p#out").append("'" + $(this).val() + "' => '" + $(this).text() + "'<br/>");
    });
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3UfRq/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the `option` childs, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/xavier_seignard/3UfRq/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#state option').map(function(i, opption) {
    $('#out').append(i + ' => ' + option.text + '<br/>');
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r75Te/)